# Can't find apache error logs

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

It seems my server doesn't have error logs . i can't find them anywhere . in info.php file there is no mention about any error log. 
 I tried commands like pico /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log ,but of course,no results.
  How can i find the apache error logs and view them ?

thanks for the help

Comment: this is a perfect question for Google I think :-)

Comment: ok, to help you a little bit: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/ ;-)

Comment: thanks,but i already tried that. nothing happens. maybe i do something wrong..i am a newbie ..

Comment: find your httpd.conf and try: grep 'ErrorLog\|CustomLog' httpd.conf

Comment: and if you don't know where it is, try: find / -name httpd.conf -exec grep 'ErrorLog\|CustomLog' {} \;

Comment: also you can tell what's your OS/distro and what type of Apache you use (from distribution/tarball/xampp etc.)

Comment: when running the command i get ' No such file or directory'

Comment: try the second one...

Comment: id did  .after i login as root,i typed that command,the second one,but i still get no such file or directory i have  CentOS 5.5-64

Comment: On CentOS it should be /var/log/httpd/error_log and /var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: Or maybe your server really doesn't have logs... You can try: grep 'ErrorLog' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to see if it's set there or not

Comment: hmm not working,i get no such file or directory. and that command gives no results..nothing happens .do i have to do anything else ? i just typed what you gave me

Comment: Do you really have Apache installed on the machine?
If yes, there should be httpd.conf somewhere. You can find it with: find / -name httpd.conf , preferably executed with root privileges (i.e. sudo)

Comment: ok,i see DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log" when i run httpd -V i run pico(or nano) /var/logs/error_log ,it opens it,but with nothing in it thanks for the help,really amazing help :)

Answer (score 6):

Default apache error log location, by distro's:

RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora - **/var/log/httpd/error_log**
Debian / Ubuntu - **/var/log/apache2/error.log**
FreeBSD - **/var/log/httpd-error.log**

To find exact apache error log file location, you can use grep command:

```
# grep ErrorLog /usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf
# grep ErrorLog /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# grep ErrorLog /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Sample output:

```
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a 
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd-error.log"
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/).

Answer (score 1):

To add what is already given, you can try this (if you are not sure what distro you are running):

```
[root@centos ~]# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   May  4 2011 06:51:15
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Note DEFAULT_ERRORLOG line.